# I have a migration problem when the field type is string SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1215

Tags: laravel, migration, schema

```
In Connection.php line 664:
  SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1215 Cannot add foreign key constraint (SQL: alter table `point_deliveries` add constraint `point_d
  eliveries_city_ref_foreign` foreign key (`city_ref`) references `cities` (`ref`))

In Connection.php line 458:
  SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1215 Cannot add foreign key constraint
```

I link the tables so...

```
//parent
Schema::create('cities', function(Blueprint $table)
        {
            $table->increments('id');
            $table->string('title')->nullable();
            $table->string('ref');
            $table->integer('country_id')->index()->unsigned()->nullable();
            $table->foreign('country_id')->references('id')->on('countries');
        });

//child
Schema::create('point_deliveries', function (Blueprint $table)
        {
            $table->increments('id');
            $table->string('title')->nullable();
            $table->string('ref')->nullable();
            $table->string('city_ref');
            $table->foreign('city_ref')->references('ref')->on('cities');
        });
```

how to tie them? There is no problem with the field integer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Column must be Indexed

In order to create a Foreign Key constraint, the column on the table you are linking to must be indexed. I would suggest you make the `ref` field unique on the cities table thus giving it an index and ensuring you only have a single item to link to.

```
//parent
Schema::create('cities', function(Blueprint $table)
        {
            $table->increments('id');
            $table->string('title')->nullable();
            $table->string('ref')->unique();;
            $table->integer('country_id')->index()->unsigned()->nullable();
            $table->foreign('country_id')->references('id')->on('countries');
        });

//child
Schema::create('point_deliveries', function (Blueprint $table)
        {
            $table->increments('id');
            $table->string('title')->nullable();
            $table->string('ref')->nullable();
            $table->string('city_ref');
            $table->foreign('city_ref')->references('ref')->on('cities');
        });
```

Answer (score 1):

You can only have a foreign key referencing a unique field. Modify your cities table so that the ref field is unique, like this:

```
// cities

$table->string('ref')->unique();
```

Comment: Thank! You helped me! "+1"

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you have table engine set to InnoDB by default or set it explicitly with $table->engine = 'InnoDB';

Also here is the Docs for 5.8, hopefully this helps you.

https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/migrations